# Running an invoke or query operation forces the chaincode container to restart

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am not sure if the community is aware of this problem but I tried to run the balance-transfer application under [fabric samples]: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples. Everything seems to run smoothly. However, when running a query or an invoke operation, the docker container containing the chaincode crashes and gets restarted. You can check it out by running 
`docker ps -a`. The status will show that the container had just started.

I looked up the logs of the peer that was queried and it seems the problem resides somewhere here:

`2018-01-17 07:06:33.654 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 891 waiting for container(dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0) lock
2018-01-17 07:06:33.654 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 892 got container (dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0) lock
2018-01-17 07:06:33.655 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 893 Cleanup container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
****2018-01-17 07:06:33.693 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> ERRO 894 Error handling chaincode support stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled****
2018-01-17 07:06:33.693 UTC [chaincode] deregisterHandler -> DEBU 895 Deregister handler: mycc:v0
2018-01-17 07:06:34.343 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 896 Stopped container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
2018-01-17 07:06:34.343 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 897 Kill container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0 (API error (409): {"message":"Cannot kill container: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0: Container d818357f76068ab0a9efbf70be9b9a19fd7f6cc7bbe11eaba95c0a61d208ceac is not running"}
)
2018-01-17 07:06:34.459 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 898 Removed container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
2018-01-17 07:06:34.459 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 899 Start container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
2018-01-17 07:06:34.459 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 89a Create container: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
2018-01-17 07:06:34.724 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 89b Created container: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0-f021beca29998638e0bb7caa7af8fda7f1e709518214a3181d259abcb2347093`

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: It turns out this problem only occurs when hyperledger fabric v1.1.0-preview is used.

Comment: I ran the balance transfer and I can't make reproduce your error... do you still have it?

Answer (score 0):

***There exist two types of chaincode***

1. System chaincode (part of peer binary)
2. Application chaincode (developed by smart contract/chaincode developers)

System chaincodes are part of the peer binary itself, whereas application chaincodes are instantiated in docker containers. There are various system chaincodes like LSCC, CSCC, QSCC, etc.
LSCC refers to the Life cycle system chaincode, it manages the life cycle of application chaincode. 
LSCC contains various chaincode related logics like installation logic, instantiation logic, up-gradation logic, invoking and querying logic.

---

So, the point is

**If** 
 the chaincode container is already up and running
 then, The Query/Invoke function get executed and the result is returned to the 
 caller. 
**else** 
  due to any reason if the chaincode container is killed and not running to serve 
  the requests over gRPC
  then,
  the LSCC invoking/querying logic launches the chaincode container again until 
  it's ready to serve the requests make by the caller.